# Spring test: ApplicationContext configuration classes (spring data mongodb)

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I only want to test mongo related code. This is my test code snippet:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MongoConfig.class})
@SpringBootTest
public class ModelTest {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

As you can see I'm using `@ContextConfiguration` in order to only load Mongo related configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomConversions customConversions(){
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<Converter<?, ?>>();
        converters.add(new ReferenceWriterConverter());
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
    }

}
```

As you can see it's only intented to load custom converters are going to be used by `mongoTemplate` in order to serialize objects to mongodb database.

Also, `src/test/resources/application.properties` is:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host: localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port: 27017
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to run test it's getting me an `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoTemplate'`:

> UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital.mongo.ModelTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate' available

Related project dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you see by changing spring-boot-starter to spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: It's also added, but it has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: remove this  spring-boot-starter

Comment: I doesn't work. I'm trying to load mongoTemplate. It's nothing to do with RestTemplates!

Answer (score 0):

Seems issue you are trying to load custom mongo configuration @Bean client here or extend `AbstractMongoConfiguration`.

change your database name here instead of `demo`

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

   @Override
   protected String getDatabaseName() {
      return "demo";
   }

  @Override
   public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    return new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
  }

   @Bean
   public CustomConversions customConversions(){
       List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<Converter<?, ?>>();
       converters.add(new ReferenceWriterConverter());
       return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
   }
```

}